# 1/nb, (given b=1/150) answer is: 150/n. How??

Tags: linear-algebra, economics, simplicial-stuff

P = 1/nb + c

Given: b=1/150 and c = 17,000

The answer is: P= 150/n + 17,000, but how?

How do 1/(n*1/150) turn into 150/n?

Can someone please explain? Thank you!

Comment: Your expression is ambiguous.  Do you mean $\frac 1{nb}$ or $\frac 1n b$?  Presumably you want the former, in which case just remark that $\frac 1{1/k}=k$

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

You need the following properties:

- $\frac{a\cdot b}{c\cdot d} = \frac{a}{c}\cdot\frac{b}{d}$
- $1=1\cdot 1=1\cdot \frac11$
- $\frac{\frac ab}{\frac cd} = \frac{ad}{bc}$

I assume you already know these properties. Then, you have

$$\frac{1}{n\cdot \frac{1}{150}} = \frac{1\cdot \frac11}{n\cdot \frac{1}{150}} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{\frac11}{\frac1{150}}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{150\cdot 1}{1\cdot 1}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot 150$$